# What happens if client send SYN to udp server

Tags: tcp, udp, protocols

I want to scan udp ports with SYN flag. But how would udp server react to the SYN packet, when the udp port is open and not open?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [networkengineering.se]

Comment: @Jim Garrison I agree. Maybe it's off-topic indeed. I just meet this problem when programming.

Comment: Just remove "Java" from the tags or describe, how is you question related to it.

Comment: You can't possibly 'meet this problem when programming'. It doesn't exist. There is no such problem. It can't be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are not flags field (including SYN flag) in the [UDP header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#Packet_structure). So, technically speaking, it is not possible to send SYN packet using UDP protocol.

If you try to send TCP-formatted packet with protocol value 17 (UDP), the checksum will not match, and the packet will be discarded.

Comment: Also TDP and UDP ports are distinct, so sending a TCP segment to a UDP port is impossible.